# Why doesn't strcpy use a const pointer for dest?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, strcpy

Is there a reason strcpy's signature is this:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

instead of this?

```
char *strcpy(char *const dest, const char *src);
```

As far as I know, the function will never change the pointer.

Am I misunderstanding what const pointers should be used for? In my mind, when a function I write accepts a pointer which won't be changed (via realloc, etc.), then I mark it as a const pointer so the caller can be assured their pointer won't be moved on them. (In case they have other structs/etc. referencing that pointer location that would become outdated)

Is that an OK practice, or will it have unintended consequences?

Comment: I think a constant can only be initialized/assighned/defined once or is defined upon declaration.

Comment: Not only _the function will never change the pointer._, but there is no way `strcpy` could change `dest` anyway even without const.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The source code for `strcpy` is very roughly this:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
  while (*dest++ = *src++);
}
```

Here we actually do modify `dest` but this has no consequence for the caller because inside the `strcpy`function, `dest` is a local variable.

But following code won't compile because `dest` is const:

```
char *strcpy(char * const dest, const char *src)
{
  while (*dest++ = *src++);
}
```

we would need to write this:

```
char *strcpy(char * const dest, const char *src)
{
  char *temp = dest;
  while (*temp++ = *src++);
}
```

which introduces a non necessary `temp` variable.

Comment: Note: the 3 examples do not return value for a `char *strcpy()` function rendering them UB - of course they are _rough_.   It will be interesting to see code without a "non necessary temp variable" that returns the original `dest` as specified in the C library.

Comment: @chux you are perfecly right, but it's just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Qualifiers on function arguments are **completely ignored** in declarations (prototypes). This is required by the C language, and it makes sense, because there is no possible meaning such qualification could have to callers of the function.

In the case of `const char *src`, the argument `src` is not what's qualified; the type it points to is qualified. In your hypothetical declaration for `dest`, the qualifier applies to `dest` and is thus meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

`char *foo(char *const dest, const char *src) { ... }` means the pointer `dest` will not change in the body of the function.

It does not mean the data pointed to by `dest` will or will not change.

`const char *src` assures the calling code that the data pointed to by `src` will not change.

In calling a function like `strcpy(d,s)` or `foo(d,s)`, the calling code does not care if the function changes *its* copy of the pointer.  All the calling code cares about is if the data pointed to by `s` or `d` is changed and that is control by the `const` of the left side of `*`

```
char *dest,     // data pointed by `dest` may or may not change.
const char *src // data pointed by `src` will not change change because of `src`.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is meaningless to mark it as const as you suggest. In C, function arguments are passed as copy. It means that the variable `dest` inside `strcpy()` is actually a new variable (pushed on the stack), which holds the same content (here, the address).

Look at this function prototype:

```
void foo(int const a);
```

This has no semantic value, because we know that the original variable a that we passed to `foo()` can't be changed because it is a copy. Only the copy will potentially change. When foo return, we are guaranteed that the original variable `a` is unchanged.

In function parameters, you want to use the keyword const only if the function could actually persistently change the state of the variable. For example:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

This marks the content of the variable `s` (ie, the value stored at the address `s` points to) as const. Therefore, you are guaranteed your string will be unchanged when strlen returns.

Answer (score -1):

> As far as I know, the function will never change the pointer.

Yes, but you can. You are free to change the pointer. No need to make `dest` pointer `const`.

For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s = "Hello";
    char *d = malloc(6);

    strcpy(d, s);
    puts(d);
    strcpy(d, "World");
    puts(d);
}
```